# Sane way to continue working on local git repo while awaiting a pull request

Tags: git, github

I currently have `master` synced with `upstream` on github, and a working branch, which we can just call `working`. `working` is 1 commit ahead of `master` with an open pull request upstream.

I want to continue working on the same files, building on my committed changes, but plan to not append these to the current PR, instead waiting for upstream merge before submitting anymore changes.

If you had a repo in this state, what would you do next as far as branching, merging, etc., before making more changes, to hopefully make the next upstream rebase as painless as possible?

Comment: Was your question answered? If so, consider accepting it. If not, please help us to help you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Option A:

Work on your branch (maybe create a new branch to lessen possible confusion) and as soon as the PR is merged rebase your work onto the updated `master` branch.

#### Option B:

If you are confident that the PR (I assume against `master`) will be accepted as-is you could do something like the following:

```
$ git checkout master
Switched to branch 'master'
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'
$ git checkout -b future-master
Switched to new branch 'future-master'
$ git merge working
```

This should result in `future-master` having the same state as master will be in after the PR.

Continue working (maybe create a new branch for less confusion) and as soon as the PR gets merged you rebase your work:

```
$ git fetch origin
$ git rebase origin/master
```

The amount of merge conflicts should be minimal (in most cases zero)

---

Side note: If your `working` branch is really only 1 commit ahead. I don't think that **Option A** is any better than the simpler **Option B**.

For more complicated cases it might help. **ymmv**

Comment: Thx. If I have `branchA` 1 commit ahead of `master`, is there any difference between making new `branchB` off of `branchA`, as opposed to new `branchB` off `master` then merge `branchA` as you described?

Comment: If you are one commit ahead. Branch from `master`. Merge `branchA`. `git` will do a fast-forward merge (if not told otherwise) which should result in exactly the same state as if you branched from `branchA` directly